# Do we have free will or does Hashem know everything?

Tags: theology

Does Hashem know the future? If not, how is he God? Doesn’t God know everything?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!